# Why is a printed null treated differently from a literal null in a condition?

Tags: bash, shell

Both of these commands having the same result makes sense:

```
$ if 1; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
-bash: 1: command not found
failure

$ if $(printf 1); then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
-bash: 1: command not found
failure
```

because `$(printf "1")` is printing `1` before `1` is then executed in the `if`.

Given that, though, I don't understand why these produce different results:

```
$ if ""; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
-bash: : command not found
failure

$ if ; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

$ if $(printf ""); then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
success
```

Why would the null string output by `$(printf "")` be treated differently than the null string coded explicitly as `""` in the first command or the missing argument from the 2nd command? What is it that's being executed in the final command and found to succeed and why?

---

Update - making sure I get it!

So applying [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56171102/1745001) to the scripts above I've added explanations (please correct me if I got anything wrong):

```
$ if 1; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
-bash: 1: command not found
failure
```

The shell parses `if 1;`, sees something that it expects to be a command but is actually the number `1` and so fails "command not found"

```
$ if $(printf 1); then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
-bash: 1: command not found
failure
```

The shell parses `if $(printf 1);`, sees something that it expects to be a command, `$(printf 1)`, executes it successfully which outputs 1. The shell sees that something was output (`1`) and given any output in this context the shell expects that "something" to also be a command that it should able to execute but is actually the number 1 and so fails "command not found".

```
$ if ""; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
-bash: : command not found
failure
```

The shell parses `if "";`, sees something that it expects to be a command but is actually the string "" and so fails "command not found"

```
$ if ; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

The shell parses `if ;`, does not find the command it expected to find  in that context and so fails "syntax error"

```
$ if $(printf ""); then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
success
```

The shell parses `if $(printf "");`, sees something that it expects to be a command, `$(printf "")`, executes it successfully which outputs nothing which the shell accepts as such and so has no new command to execute and so applies the success exit status of the last command it did run (`$(printf "")`) to the condition as a whole and so succeeds.

Comment: It's the difference between the *parser* failing to find the necessary syntactic construct and the *evaluator* finding an empty compound-list to evaluate. I can't find the reference at the moment, but I think POSIX specifies that an empty command be treated as succeeding vacuously.

Comment: I've added an answer; I think I hit all the important details.

Comment: To me, the difference between the cases $(printf 1) and $(printf "") remain unclear; the answers to these two cases, surmised by Ed Morton (for which effort, thanks), resp. 'executes it successfully which outputs 1 which the shell again expects to be a "command"' and 'executes it successfully which outputs nothing which the shell accepts as such', to me seems to beg the question: 'ok, but why -- why the 'expecting' on the one hand and the 'accepting' in the other?'.

Comment: My understanding: If there's something present after the original command executes then that something is treated as a command itself and executed otherwise it's not. In either case the final exit status is the exit status of the last command executed. I updated my descriptions to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Doesn't it boil down to lojza's answer below?  May I (a real question here) surmise that answer as the difference between `eval 1; echo $?` (echo's 127 [\*),and `eval ""; echo $?` (echo's 0)?     [* unless a real command '1' exists of course]

Comment: Make sure you also understand `if $(false); then`

Comment: @WilliamPursell `$(false)` outputs nothing and the last command executed was `false` which has a failure exit status so it fits right in with everything described so far, in parituclar the `if $(printf ""); then` case but now with a failure rather than success exit status from the last command executed.

Comment: @Roadowl I'm sorry I can't understand what your comment is trying to say. But no, lojzas answer is showing the issue in a slightly different context and then trying to work around the issue, it's not explaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: the null string output by `printf` disappears during the word-splitting process applied to the command substitution before the shell tries to perform command lookup on it.

---

When the shell reads its input, it needs to read and parse an entire command before it evaluates the command.

After reading `if`, the parser is committed to parsing an entire `if` statement before it does any evaluation. The next thing it expects is a compound list to serve as the condition. A compound list cannot begin with a semicolon, though, so the parser immediately signals an error when it sees `if ;`.

Skipping a little bit of detail, suffice to say that the string `$(print "")` *does* parse as a compound list. No evaluation is required yet, so `if $(print ""); then ...` successfully parses.

After parsing is complete, now the shell actually has to *evaluate* it. The process of doing so is documented under "SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION" in the `bash` man page, quoted below in its entirety with relevant passages highlighted:

> SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION
>
> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to
>   right.
>
> 1. The  words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are
>      saved for later process-
>                ing.
> 2. **The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded.**  If any words remain after expansion, the
>      first word is taken to  be
>                the name of the command and the remaining words are the arguments.
> 3. Redirections are performed as described above under REDIRECTION.
> 4. The  text  after the = in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution,
>      arithmetic expansion,
>                and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.
>
>    If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell environment.  Otherwise, the variables are added to the
>      environment  of
>         the  executed  command and do not affect the current shell environment.  If any of the assignments attempts to assign a value to
>      a readonly variable,
>         an error occurs, and the command exits with a non-zero status.
>
>    If no command name results, redirections are performed, but do not affect the current shell environment.  A redirection error causes
>      the  command  to
>         exit with a non-zero status.
>
>    **If there is a command name left after expansion,** execution proceeds as described below.  **Otherwise, the command exits.**  If one of
>      the expansions con-
>         tained a command substitution, **the exit status of the command is the exit status of the last command substitution performed.**  If
>      there were  no  com-
>         mand substitutions, the command exits with a status of zero.

So, `$(print "")` succeeds but expands to an empty list of words. As a result, the condition for the `if` statement "executes" by immediately returning with the exit status of the command substitution, resulting in the true branch being taken.

Comment: I think much of the confusion stems from the use of the terms 'parse', 'execute', 'evaluate', 'expand', 'substitution', and the colloquial use of them that doesn't necessarily concur with the 'offical' use as per the manpage. I feel the urgent need for a diagram of some sorts.

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I get it now. I updated my question to add an explanation for the behavior of each of the commands I started with, if you wouldn't mind taking a glance at that to make sure I got each of them right i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at exit codes:

```
$ 1; echo $?
1: command not found
127

$ $(printf 1); echo $?
1: command not found
127

$ ""; echo $?
Command '' not found    
127

$(printf ""); echo $?
0
```

You probably wanted:

```
$ if [ 1 ]; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
success

$ if [ $(printf 1) ]; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
success

$ if [ "" ]; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
failure

$ if [ $(printf "") ]; then printf "success\n"; else printf "failure\n"; fi
failure
```

Note the space  after `[` and before `]`

Check `man [`

Comment: Your first block of code is just an alternative way of creating the same issue described in my question. No, I didn't want the second block as I'm trying to **understand** why `$(printf "")` produces a different exit status than `""` in the first block, not find a workaround. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: `$(printf "")` produces exit code `0` because empty string was successfully printed. `""` produces exit code 127 because `""` command was not found. I thought you want to compare commands output, not exit codes - that's why I recommend `[   ]`

Comment: No, I'm trying to understand the behavior in my question. wrt `"" produces exit code 127 because "" command was not found` - yes, I know that but `$(print "")` outputs `""` and the exit code for `""` in THAT case is apparently 0. `if 1` and `if $(printf 1)` have identical results while `if ""` and `$(if printf "")` have completely opposite results and `if $(printf 1)` which generates a non-existent command has different results than `if $(print "")` which also generates a non-existent command -  THAT is what I'm asking for help to understand.

Comment: I see now. Playing with `set -x` shows that for `$(printf "")` no subshell is opened. Wish someone can find in source code where this happened :-)

Comment: I expect there was no subshell in that case because printf is a builtin rather than an external command but that's not relevant to my question. I got an answer now, thanks.